# asp.net failed to load css

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am trying to create a login form with asp.net. I am new at this language and I want to include css inside. I have used this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="~/css/style.css">
```

css is inside App_Data>css folder that is inside . And Loginaspx is inside App_Data>Application folder.

Inspect element says:

```
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found) http://localhost:3768/Register/style.css
```

Comment: seems url is wrong of css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App_Data folder is typically used to store exactly what it is labelled as... App Data (such as databases and data files), this doesn't include CSS. You're better off placing the CSS inside the folder labelled Shared and using the following code to point to it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" runat="server" media="screen" href="~/Shared/css/style.css">
```

Comment: i don't have any folder named shared. where shoul I plase it?

Comment: thank you, it works for css but for js it shows me errors about syntax  of js

Comment: The syntax errors are probably a different problem, not relating to linking of files. Feel free to ask another question about those.